# How to get job working dir in sun grid engine?

Tags: working-directory, sungridengine

Suppose we submit jobs by `qsub` under the path `/path/to/working/dir`, after jobs pending, we can get some information of jobs with `qstat`, but no **working dir** information is supplied by `qstat`.

How can we get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run a qstat -j jobId you will get output that has a field "sge_o_workdir:" that should have the info you need.  For example if your jobID is 1234 your command would look like the below.

```
qstat -j 1234
```

and the output would look like the below.

```
==============================================================
job_number:                 1234
exec_file:                  job_scripts/1234
submission_time:            Wed Oct 10 19:00:03 2012
owner:                      user
uid:                        1000
group:                      group
gid:                        1000
sge_o_home:                 /home/user
sge_o_log_name:             user
sge_o_path:                 /usr/local/packages/sge-root/bin/lx24-amd64:/usr/bin:/bin
sge_o_shell:                /bin/sh
sge_o_workdir:              /path/to/workDir
sge_o_host:                 host
account:                    sge
stderr_path_list:           NONE:NONE:/path/to/error/
mail_list:                  
notify:                     FALSE
job_name:                   myJobName
stdout_path_list:           NONE:NONE:/path/to/output/
jobshare:                   0
hard_queue_list:            all.q
env_list:                   
script_file:                /some/script.sh
project:                    
usage    1:                 cpu=00:28:22, mem=83.71677 GBs, io=252.35721, vmem=234.090M, maxvmem=256.438M
scheduling info:
```